# which label is correct: date of request/answer or request date/answer date?

Tags: labels, data-tables

i am working on a table which has 2 columns: date of request and date of answer (to the request) and i am wondering which label should i use: date of request/answer or request date/answer date?

Which is better from a UX perspective do you think?

or is it more a matter of grammar?

Comment: I don't think it really matter either way, but I would say that "Response" is a better word for "Answer", especially when paired with "Request".

Comment: If the date is when it happened another option is to use "date requested" and "date answered" or "requested/answered at". I agree with musefan that response could be a better word, if you haven't already considered that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the question.

Cognitive load on your user is an invisivble aspect of User experience and it is prominent aspect. Having said that, with the options you are proposing my suggestion would be the second. Reason:

First option is asking me to join the verb(request) with an event, and brain processes it may be a second delayed. Where as in second option- 'request date' is specifying the time event without asking my brain to do any extra grammarly process. 'Less is more'

A minor concept but effective with vast usership.

Comment: It is common in English to write a two-word description using Verb Noun form, like "cook dinner" or "answer call", so I agree with "Request Date" even though it doesn't strictly fit the rule.